# Jenkins/ClearCase Polling only Foundation Baseline

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, baseline

I'm trying to get Jenkins (version 1.616) to poll for changes every hour using the ClearCase plugin (the UCM option) for Jenkins. When Jenkins is comparing baselines, it is currently comparing the foundation baseline to the foundation baseline, instead of comparing the last baseline used to the most recent (or even recommended) baseline. Because of this, Jenkins never sees changes from ClearCase and therefore never initiates builds on its own. However, when I manually start a build, everything goes smoothly and all the changes are present in the newly-built project.

I am using jenkins 1.617 with the clearcase plugin (version 1.6).

My build trigger is "Poll SCM" with the schedule being "H * * * *".

Does anyone know how to configure Jenkins and/or the Jenkins ClearCase plugin (the UCM option) so that it compares the recommended baseline instead of the foundation baseline?  We have a hierarchy of streams and I we are polling one of the parent streams (but not the integration stream)

Answer (score -1):

You can't compare recommended baselines with Jenkins UCM plugin. It just compares the last baseline with the previous one. You can use [this tool](http://almtoolbox.com/rnd) for recommended baselines comparison.